# Check if any text in multiple spans is negative

Tags: jquery

I have a group of span tags with the same class. I am trying to use a filter function that gets a count of all the spans with a text value less than zero. I have used something similar

```js
$('#go').on('click', function(){
 var $nonneg = $('.test').filter(function(){
 return parseInt(this.text) < 0;
 });
 if ($nonneg.length !=0){
  alert('fail');
 }else{
  alert('pass');
 }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="test">0</span>
<span class="test">0</span>
<span class="test">0</span>
<span class="test">-5</span>
<br/>
<button id="go">go</button>
```

using input values, but I am trying to figure out how to do it using the .text of an element.

Comment: Try changing `this.text` to `this.innerText`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `text` property in plain JavaScript. Use [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) instead.

```js
$('#go').on('click', function(){
 var $nonneg = $('.test').filter(function(){
 return parseInt(this.textContent) < 0;
 });
 if ($nonneg.length !=0){
  alert('fail');
 }else{
  alert('pass');
 }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="test">0</span>
<span class="test">0</span>
<span class="test">0</span>
<span class="test">-5</span>
<br/>
<button id="go">go</button>
```

Comment: This works. I'm using jQuery for this, but i'll have to look into different selector for text values. Thanks for pointing this out

Comment: Instead of `this.textContent` you could also use `$(this).text()`

Comment: @user2168066 What did you mean by "i'll have to look into different selector for text values"?

Comment: I've only ever used .text(). I just left that part off of the end

Answer (score 0):

[Here's your code in a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5qtbkmxb/)

```
 $('#go').on('click', function(){
    var $nonneg = $('.test').filter(function(){
        return parseInt($(this).text()) < 0;
    });
    if ($nonneg.length !=0){
        alert('fail');
    }else{
        alert('pass');
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution without using filter.

```js
$('#go').on('click', function() {
  var lessThanZeroCount = 0;
  $('.test').each(function() {
    if (parseInt($(this).text()) < 0) {
      lessThanZeroCount++;
    }
  }).promise().done(function() { 
    alert('spans with numbers less than zero = ' + lessThanZeroCount);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="test">0</span>
<span class="test">-5</span>
<span class="test">0</span>
<span class="test">-5</span>
<span class="test">0</span>
<br/>
<button id="go">go</button>
```

Fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/vngm5xzf/